# Connecting RabbitMQ Using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, rabbitmq

I am using the sample code available at internet but I am getting an exception and I am not able to solve this error.

I am getting this exception

> BrokerUnreachableExceptionCaught None of the specified endpoints were reachable

No idea how to resolve this error. There are so many links that have posted the encounter of error but none of them have it's resolution. Please help me regarding this. Your suggestions will be helpful to me.. Please help as soon as possible.

Some links

- http://lists.rabbitmq.com/pipermail/rabbitmq-discuss/2012-September/022407.html
- http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.networking.rabbitmq.general/18329

Code:

```
try
{
    ConnectionFactory factory = new ConnectionFactory();
    factory.UserName = "user";
    factory.Password = "password";
    factory.VirtualHost = "/";
    factory.Protocol = Protocols.FromEnvironment();
    factory.HostName = "localhost";
    factory.Port = AmqpTcpEndpoint.UseDefaultPort;
    IConnection conn = factory.CreateConnection();

    //using (var connection = factory.CreateConnection())
    //{
    //    using (var channel = connection.CreateModel())
    //    {
    //        channel.QueueDeclare("hello", false, false, false, null);
    //        string message = "Hello World!";
    //        var body = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(message);

    //        channel.BasicPublish("", "hello", null, body);
    //        Console.WriteLine(" [x] Sent {0}", message);
    //    }
    //}
}
catch
{
}
```

Comment: Plz look at this post >> https://stackoverflow.com/a/70507418/5967360

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The BrokerUnreachableException thrown has the following useful properties:

ConnectionAttempts
ConnectionErrors

Take a look at these to see if there's any extra information (for example, perhaps the password is incorrect.)

Comment: yes , I was giving user name and password from my end, I removed username and password lines , and it starts Working. Can you please suggest how can I check id queue is getting something or not. Can we check if something got saved in the queue or not?

Comment: Actually   var ea = (BasicDeliverEventArgs)consumer.Queue.Dequeue(); is not returning anything. It is not returning anything. Please help me ASAP.

Comment: @Sandy, please post another question regarding the Dequeue problem with some example code, and link to it in a comment, I'll take a look.

Comment: Just thought, you might find it really useful to add the web management plugin to your Rabbit broker, and log into that (http://www.rabbitmq.com/management.html). You can then see the queues, and look at the messages in that management UI.

Comment: Sir, please have a look at this question and please help me.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18959927/rabbitmq-in-webapplication-with-multiple-users

Answer (score 1):

RabbitMQ localhost connection in Asp.net core, in Nugget Package, browse **RabbitMQ.Client**

//localhost connection, these both worked for me.

```
var factory = new ConnectionFactory() { HostName = "localhost" };
```

or

```
var factory = new ConnectionFactory();

using (var connection = factory.CreateConnection())
        {
            using (var channel = connection.CreateModel())
            {
                channel.QueueDeclare(queue: "HelloNewWorld",
                             durable: false,
                             exclusive: false,
                             autoDelete: false,
                             arguments: null);
                             
                             string message = "Hello World!";
        var body = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(message);

        channel.BasicPublish(exchange: "",
                             routingKey: "HelloNewWorld",
                             basicProperties: null,
                             body: body);
        Console.WriteLine(" [x] Sent {0}", message);
            }
        
        }

//default localhost for rabbitmq
http://localhost:15672/queues
```

[image]

## Asp.NetCore #RabbitMQ