# RabbitMQ Connection refused 127.0.0.1:5672

Tags: asp.net, .net-core, rabbitmq

I am preparing a simple ASP.NET Core MVC web application.

I have installed RabbitMQ server to my laptop. RabbitMQ Management UI is running on `localhost:15672`.

Rabbit MQ cluster name is like: `rabbit@CR00001.ABC.COM.LOCAL`

I am trying to send message to rabbitmq in controller. But I am getting **None of the specified endpoints were reachable** error.

If I use 'localhost' as host name, I get **Connection refused 127.0.0.1:5672** in inner exceptions.

If I use `rabbit` as host name, I get **Name or service not known**

I've tried to solve the problem according to other StackOverflow questions, however, none of them could solved my problem.

**Home controller:**

```
        [HttpPost]
        public void SendMessage([FromBody]Message message)
        {
            try
            {
                var factory = new ConnectionFactory()
                {
                    UserName = _username,
                    Password = _password,
                    HostName = _hostname,
                    VirtualHost = "/",
                    Port = _port,
                };
                using (var connection = factory.CreateConnection())
                using (var channel = connection.CreateModel())
                {
                    channel.QueueDeclare(queue: _queueName,
                                         durable: false,
                                         exclusive: false,
                                         autoDelete: false,
                                         arguments: null);

                    var body = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(message.Text);

                    channel.BasicPublish(exchange: "",
                                         routingKey: _queueName,
                                         basicProperties: null,
                                         body: body);
                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }
        }
```

**appsettings.json**

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "RabbitMq": {
    "Hostname": "localhost",
    "QueueName": "WordQueue",
    "UserName": "test",
    "Password": "test",
    "Port": 5672
  }
}
```

Here is test user configuration in Rabbit MQ Management UI
[image: test user configuration]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you setup your `test` user in the UI portal? This is probably the cause of your connection refused error. You can setup users via http://localhost:15672/#/users.

You should also debug your `factory` to check that your config values are being passed in correctly

I would also suggest that you pop some code in your catch to ensure you aren't missing an exception

The references to `http://rabbit` are for use within containers. These will only work if you are running both your ASPNET and Rabbit applications within a containerised network (for example Docker Compose). I found using containers was a much better approach for learning RabbitMq.

Apprciate that this is going a little off-topic now, but if you are not familiar with containerisation I would suggest taking a look at this post (and the respective series) from Wolfgang Ofner https://www.programmingwithwolfgang.com/rabbitmq-in-an-asp-net-core-3-1-microservice/ and the getting started with Docker from Brad Traversy on YouTube https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Kyx2PsuwomE

Answer (score 2):

After create user, do not forget set permissions,
basicaly,

- can access virtual hosts (/)
- set topic permission (AMQP default)
  Note: of course you can use rabbitmq ui for this operation (create user and permissions).
  [image]

  var factory = new ConnectionFactory() { HostName = "hostname_or_ip_adres_here", UserName="username here..", Password="psw here.."
  };

this will work !

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes when installing or upgrading, we find that the mnesia database gets corrupt.  The only way we have found to fix it is to stop the service, delete the database (all files from here: C:\Users<userUsedToInstall>\AppData\Roaming\RabbitMQ\db), then start the Windows service again.

ref.
https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/rabbitmq-cookbook/9781849516501/ch12s06.html